# Jquery get animated text from other file

Tags: php, jquery, jquery-load

I'm getting a product's name & its description from an external PHP file using the jQuery "load" function. Further, I want this text to be displayed on the page using the fadeIn() function. How can I do that in my jQuery code?

```
$('document').ready(function() {
    refreshEPosts();
    function refreshEPosts(){
        $('#crPanel').load('getNewPosts.php', function(){
            setTimeout(refreshEPosts, 1500);
        });
    }
});
```

UPDATE

```
$('document').ready(function() {
    refreshEPosts();
    function refreshEPosts(){
        $('#crPanel').load('getNewPosts.php', function(data) {
            //For now, lets just log the data
            console.log(data); //should be your echo'd php stuff

            setTimeout(refreshEPosts, 1500);
            $('#crPanel').fadeIn(data);
        }); 
    }
});
```

Comment: What's being returned from the php file...right now you're just calling the `.load` function every 1.5 seconds.

Comment: it is returning name & some text from databse using mysql -- im just echoing it in tht page

Comment: What happens when the next lot of data is received? Should `#crPanel` fade out before it's updated with the new data?

Answer (score 0):

You have to actually do something with the return data. Add a parameter to your `load` callback, and use it:

```
$('#crPanel').load('getNewPosts.php', function(data) {
    //For now, lets just log the data
    console.log(data); //should be your echo'd php stuff

    setTimeout(refreshEPosts, 1500);
});
```

Comment: Wherever you want to `fadeIn` the data. So, `$("#yourSelector").fadeIn(data)`

Comment: What's your console say about the AJAX request, is it completing?

Comment: So when you say not working, what's actually happening? And is the correct data being logged?

Comment: The data doesn't animate i mean fades in, it just displays like normally just like normal appearance

Comment: Well yeah, there's no animate function! You have to make one!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

HTML:

```
<div id="myDiv"></div>
```

JS:

```
$('#crPanel').load('getNewPosts.php', function(data) {
    $("#myDiv").fadeIn(data); 
    setTimeout(refreshEPosts, 1500);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this would work:

```
$('document').ready(function() {
    refreshEPosts();

    function refreshEPosts(){
        $('#crPanel')
            .hide()
            .load('getNewPosts.php', function() {
                $('#crPanel').fadeIn();

                setTimeout(refreshEPosts, 1500);
            }); 
    }
});
```

You can see it working in principle in this jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/M93Cn/

Answer (score 0):

The `$('#crPanel').load()` just place the returned HTML into the `#crPanel` when succeed so there is no need to deal with the returned data in the success function.

As `fadeIn()` does not have a parameter that accept the data you want to display, calling `$('#crPanel').fadeIn(data);` will not work in this case, just use `$('#crPanel').fadeIn();` and I believe it will work pretty well.